# Complete Analysis fails to analyze ApplicationManifest.xml

Tags: xml, sonarqube, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines

We are facing this issue from a couple of weeks where SonarQube Complete Analysis VSTS task started failing while trying to analyze ApplicationManifest.xml.

Similar issues are being observed for other customer projects and this happens only for Azure Service Fabric projects. SonarQube analysis fails for all the XMLs under the `ApplicationPackageRoot` and `ApplicationParameters` folders of the Service Fabric project.

Why does it fail and how can we fix it?

Error Stack Trace:

```
##[error]ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
##[error]org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Unable to analyse file D:/agenttst/_work/5/s/SFApp/SFApp/ApplicationPackageRoot/ApplicationManifest.xml
##[error]at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.processException(XmlSensor.java:195)
##[error]at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.execute(XmlSensor.java:158)
##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:182)
##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)
##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:242)
##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:240)
##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:232)
##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
##[error]at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:118)
##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
##[error]at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
##[error]at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
##[error]at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
##[error]at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
##[error]at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
##[error]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to highlight file [moduleKey=SFProj_Test:SFProj_Test:EB984197-FA92-447D-95EC-6EFB5617045F, relative=ApplicationPackageRoot/ApplicationManifest.xml, basedir=D:\agenttst\_work\5\s\SFApp\SFApp]
##[error]at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.highlighting.internal.DefaultHighlighting.highlight(DefaultHighlighting.java:84)
##[error]at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.highlighting.internal.DefaultHighlighting.highlight(DefaultHighlighting.java:36)
##[error]at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.saveSyntaxHighlighting(XmlSensor.java:115)
##[error]at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.runChecks(XmlSensor.java:104)
##[error]at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.execute(XmlSensor.java:154)
##[error]... 31 more
##[error]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 1454 is not a valid offset for file [moduleKey=SFProj_Test:SFProj_Test:EB984197-FA92-447D-95EC-6EFB5617045F, relative=ApplicationPackageRoot/ApplicationManifest.xml, basedir=D:\agenttst\_work\5\s\SFApp\SFApp]. Max offset is 1451
##[error]at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
##[error]at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newPointer(DefaultInputFile.java:268)
##[error]at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newRange(DefaultInputFile.java:263)
##[error]at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.highlighting.internal.DefaultHighlighting.highlight(DefaultHighlighting.java:82)
##[error]... 35 more
##[error]ERROR:
##[error]ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
##[error]The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully.
```

Steps to reproduce issue:
1. Create a sample Azure Service fabric project in Visual Studio.
2. Run SonarQube analysis steps for the Service Fabric project source.

We are using SonarQube 6.1 with SonarXML 1.4.3.1027

Please let me know if you'd need any further information.

Comment: Do you use 2.* version of sonarqube tasks? Set System.Debug to true and queue build, then post the detail build log here.

Comment: Could you please provide an example `ApplicationManifest.xml` file? It seems to me like the xml cannot be parsed by SonarXML.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam It is `SonarXML 1.4.3.1027`

Comment: Analyzing the azure example from the official docs works fine... https://sonarcloud.io/code?id=AzureExample&selected=AzureExample%3AApplicationManifest.xml

Comment: What do you mean analysis the azure example from official docs works fine? Could you provide the ApplicationManifest.xml?

Comment: @starain-MSFT, the detailed log for SonarQube End Analysis task is exceeding the no. of characters allowed in a text field here, can you please let me know of any other source by which i can send you the log for investigation.

Comment: @slartidan, I'm using the default ApplicationManifest.xml that i get when i create a sample Service Fabric project from VS 2015. Unfortuantely i'm not able to add the content here due to length restrictions.

Comment: You can share the log and applicationmanifest.xml on the OneDrive.

Comment: Here is the link to onedrive for ApplicationManifest.xml and complete sonarqube analysis logs: https://microsoft-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/personal/v-sandem_microsoft_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?share=Etcytdzh5lVJtNVGFmYRcggBG-HS1JExa3WaYOan_h5T-w . Please let me know if any further information is required

Comment: Can someone let me know if you were able to reproduce the issue and know the reason. Appreciate any kind of help!